# tcpprobe does't exist in /proc/net/ when I used SSH

Tags: shell, monitoring, mininet

I am new in world of network. I made a simple SDN that contains 3 hosts, one switch and a controller. I would like to monitor the traffic using tcpprobe. I opened a terminal using xterm h1 and ran the shell there. I also made iperf server in h2. But the tcpprobe was not existed in /proc/net/ directory when I use a SSH terminal!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMj3b.png)

However I installed it on my VM and it is exist in /proc/net/ of my VM.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzVlo.png)

```
sudo apt-get install transcode
```

Here is my shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#used variables
eth=h1-eth0
port_to_probe=5001
#we will probe the iperf port
server_addr=10.0.0.2

#LOAD TCP CONGESTION CONTROL MODULES
modprobe tcp_probe port=$port_to_probe full=1 bufsize=50

for time_test in 10 20 30 60 10 20
do

echo "Traffic transmission time set to " $time_test "s randomly.\n"

#start logging data
sudo cat /proc/net/tcpprobe > tcprobe.dat &

#get the cat process ID to later kill it
pid=$!
#kill the logger
kill $pid

done
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, each SSH use a port to connect to VM and this cause a change on the address of `/proc/net/.` To solve this problem it is enough to change the mentioned address to `/proc/6337/net/`. By reading this address in fact you read the real VM directory. So the final code will change to:

```
cat /proc/6337/net/tcpprobe
```